# How can I fix where template references are in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular9

I recently upgraded Angular from 8 to 9 and as soon as I did that I started getting compile errors and I cannot get the app working again. It seems as though the modules that my templates use are pointing to the wrong place (doubled up end points).

Here is an example of what it is outputting.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/components/prod/settings-dashboard/font-page/font-page.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
'../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/common/common' in 
'/Users/person/Projects/appilicious/src/app/components/prod/settings-dashboard/font-page'
```

As you can notice it has common reference twice, which seeing how I don't really know of the template module reference works, I am confused about it. I am not using these in the component so I assume it is template based.

It is mainly for common as well as for forms. I am guessing there is a setup file that I am not changing but I haven't had luck finding where this would live.

My package.json is using angular at ~9.0.6

I have a fresh project with angular 9 and that one works flawlessly...

Answer (score 0):

The `ng update` command must have messed up some of your imports.

Check all `import { ... } from '/path/to/module';` and make sure the `path/to/module` is correct.

From your error message, it seems that the `@angular/common` module reference has somehow been replaced with `@angular/common/common` which is incorrect and leads the compiler to not find the specified module.

So, this is a very superficial error that you should be able to fix quickly.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. I looked under `node_modules/@angular/common` and it doesn't seem to have another folder called `common`. I have found the solution  which I will post - Thanks for the help!

Comment: I meant, check the `import` statements in your code. They must be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check all your paths are correct to your components and modules.

For your common module, try to remove your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`.

Then run `npm cache clean -f` and `npm i` (which is an alias for `npm install`).

Comment: Did not solve it unfortunately but thanks for the recommendation on `npm cache clean`.

Answer (score 0):

I made the mistake of creating an `index.ts` type file to hold all my modules. Not entirely certain whether this is bad practice - though this may be unnecessary. So basically:

```
modules.ts

export {CommonModule} from '@angular/common'
```

And had a SharedModule calling it

```
shared.module.ts

import {CommonModule} from '../modules'

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    exports: [CommonModule]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Once I used only the direct reference it worked. Not sure why it would do that but it causes a bit of confusion. Weird thing is this only did it for `FormsModule` and `CommonModule`.